# Postgres generate_series() of given length

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, datetime, date-arithmetic

We can generate a datetime array with specified bin-width using:

```
select generate_series( 
  timestamp without time zone '2020-10-01 00:00:00', '2020-10-04 00:00:00', 
  '24 hours') as ts

          ts
1 2020-10-01
2 2020-10-02
3 2020-10-03
4 2020-10-04
```

Is it possible to generate an array of set length i.e. a given number of bins/breaks?

I want to provide a date range and number of equal intervals to divide it into.

Comment: Which result are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> I want to provide a date range and number of equal intervals to divide it into

You can use `generate_series()` with integers, and date arithmetics:

```
with params as (
    select 
        timestamp '2020-10-01' ts_start, 
        timestamp '2020-10-04' ts_end,
        3                      num   
)
select ts_start + (ts_end - ts_start) * i / num as ts
from params
cross join lateral generate_series(0, num) s(i)
```

This splits the given time range into 3 intervals (resulting in a total of 4 timestamps).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cf6231d5059acf5d495e2b13f8943ce8)**:

```
| ts                  |
| :------------------ |
| 2020-10-01 00:00:00 |
| 2020-10-02 00:00:00 |
| 2020-10-03 00:00:00 |
| 2020-10-04 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB but this still sets the interval to 24 hours, yielding a sequence of length 4.  I'd like the output of length n. I meant _series_ rather than array.

Comment: @geotheory: so you want to provide a  starting date and a number of iterations, and generate the corresponding series from these two parameters, is that right?

Comment: Close :) I want to provide a date range and number of equal intervals to divide it into.

Comment: @geotheory: ok, it was not *that* clear in your question... See my update.